# Will a larger or smaller body of water lose heat faster?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy

Say you fill a bucket full of hot water, and you fill another bucket half full of hot water. The water is the same temperature and the room conditions are the same. Which one loses heat first?

Apologies if this question has been asked before and/or is obvious, but I wasn't able to find any answers, and I have no knowledge of physics to attempt to answer this question myself.

Comment: -1 What do you think?

Comment: Do you mean which cools down faster, or do you mean which loses more heat?

Comment: @sammygerbil Just because the answer is obvious to you, doesn't mean it was/is obvious to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question can generally be answered using [Newton's Law of Cooling.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convective_heat_transfer#Newton's_law_of_cooling) Wikipedia says:

> The basic relationship for heat transfer by convection is:
>
> $${\dot {Q}}=hA(T_{a}-T_{b})$$ where ${\dot {Q}}$ is the heat
>   transferred per unit time, $A$ is the area of the object, $h$ is the
>   heat transfer coefficient, $T_a$ is the object's surface temperature
>   and $T_b$ is the fluid temperature.

Now, I'm gonna call the two buckets 1 and 2 and denote them by subscripts. We can rephrase your question as '*is $\dot{Q_1}>\dot{Q_2}$*?' Let's examine them variable by variable...

### $h$

This one is the heat transfer coefficient. Simply put, it's how efficient an object is at getting rid of heat. Since $h_1=h_2$, we can just pull them out.

### $T_a$ and $T_b$

$T_a$ represents the surface temperature of the object, and $T_b$ the temperature of the air around it. Since $T_{a1}=T_{a2}$ and $T_{b1}=T_{b2}$, we can pull out $(T_a - T_b)$ entirely. That just leaves us with $\dot{Q}\propto A$. Heat transfer, thus, is dictated by surface area. If we assume that the two bodies of water have minimal surface area (Which can be proven to be a sphere) then **the larger body of water has a greater surface area, and thus will lose heat faster.**

Note that 'cooling' and 'losing heat' aren't synonymous. Your larger body of water, simply due to the fact that there's more of it, has more heat energy. It'll take longer to cool, even though it's losing heat faster.

Answer (score -2):

This is an interesting question. Thank you for asking it. First let us explain what heat is. Heat is a form of energy. It's measured in joules. Heat energy and thermal energy are the same thing. Heat is related to temperature but the two are not the same.

One way to approach your question is to imagine the exact opposite. What would happen if I had a bucket of water and a little bucket of water and poured the same amount of boiling water into each bucket. I would argue that the little cup would feel much warmer. The change would be far more noticeable in the little cup. Therefore, if we reverse the conditions and imagine adding negative heat (cooling) then we would see a more noticeable difference in the little bucket. The little bucket would lose all of its energy first.

Why?

Let me begin by saying that temperature is a measure of kinetic energy of particles. That is, the faster the particle are going, the hotter they are. One common misconception is that temperature depends on mass. It does not depend on the mass of the substance.  However, the amount of heat energy that substance has does depend on the mass. If you double the mass you must double the amount of heat energy to heat it to the same temperature. Just imagine adding negative heat. Then your question follows the same principle. You must add twice as much negative heat to the larger bucket to cool it to the same temperature as the smaller bucket.

Comment: Eh... Not quite. The OP is just leaving the buckets out, so they are cooling on their own via interactions with the air.

Comment: I appreciate your concern for downvotes, but I am not wrong in my explanation. The heat is gone from the smaller bucket first. That was the original question.

Comment: Honestly, the way this question is worded, it's ambiguous. While the smaller bucket can decrease in temperature faster, the larger bucket will lose more heat energy per second.

Comment: Pouring the same amount of boiling water into each isn't a good analogy.  The buckets are at the same temperature, not total energy; so adding the same amount of heat to different masses doesn't give the same conditions.